# Problems loading image

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

example :

[image]

Image files do not work when loaded using the method

```
response()->download(public_path('/users/').$attachment->path) ;
```

The error I get is

> Could not load image 'name.jpeg'

Comment: Could you please clarify which laravel you are using? You tagged your question 5.2 as well as 5.3

Answer (score 0):

The error you say is different than the error in the image. Are you sure the jpeg is not corrupted? Can you open the image in other program? And verify the file is located in

```
/public/users/name.jpeg
```

Comment: The image is an example of the problem :)

Comment: It indicated file is corrupt or improperly formatted. Try downloading a known good image.